# Serializing unordered lists using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used Lists within a list and I intend to send the id's using jquery to another php file(updateDB.php).

I tried serializing the list but couldn't get the data. I'm not sure if i've got it right, tried looking around every place but couldn't figure out what's wrong with the code.

```
<ul>
<li id="recordsArray_<?some number?>"><?php echo content?>`

    <ul>
        <?php
        while (some condition) {
            ?>
            <div>
            <li id="subArray_<another number?>"><?php echo content?></li>
            </div>
            <?php
            //conditions - increment within the loop
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
 </li></ul>
```

the jquery code is something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $("#contentLeft ul").sortable({opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
            var order = $(this).sortable('serialize') + '&action=updateMenuListings';
            $.post("updateDB.php", order, function(theResponse) {
                $("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
            });
        }});
    });

    $(function() {
        $("#contentLeft ul li ul").sortable({opacity: 0.6, cursor: 'move', update: function() {
            var order = $(this).sortable('serialize') + '&action=updateSubListings';
            $.post("updateDB.php", order, function(theResponse) {
                $("#contentRight").html(theResponse);
            });
        }});
    });
});
```

the id's contentLeft are just the id's for  before the lists.
I intend to make it draggable hence used sortable.

On debugging, i'm unable to get any id's of the lists in the variable 'order'.

Please do check out the code and help out.

Thanks

Comment: The generated HTML is invalid -> [ul](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html)

Comment: @Andreas i've not written the code syntactically correct here since i have a lot more of variables from php being echoed for the numbers and everything.

Comment: This is not a php problem... post the resultant html if you want any hope of getting help on this.

Comment: @Orangepill I'm unable to retrieve the id's of the lists by serializing it to the variable 'order'.

Comment: Instead of posting your php code view the page source and copy the html that is produced from the php and edit your question and show that ...  that will be infinitely more useful to whoever may help you then what you are showing now.

Answer (score 0):

Below you'll find some HTML that is structure like yours along with the JavaScript and jQuery to do what you want. This allows you to move the top level items, with all their respective subitems or just rearrange the subitems. Both options generate a body that you can use in the commented out post line.

You can see it in action here: ***http://jsfiddle.net/WTjsG/***

HTML:

```
<div id="ContentLeft">Sortable With Update
    <ul id="Nav" class="sortable navLevel1">
        <li id="Nav_1">Nav1
            <!-- NOTE: format id's for UL and LI items as <name>_<int> for serialize to work properly -->
            <ul id="NavRecords_1" class="sortable navLevel2">
                <li id="Nav1_1">Nav1 Item1</li>
                <li id="Nav1_2">Nav1 Item2</li>
                <li id="Nav1_3">Nav1 Item3</li>
                <li id="Nav1_4">Nav1 Item4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="Nav_2">Nav2
            <ul id="NavRecords_2" class="sortable navLevel2">
                <li id="Nav2_1">Nav2 Item1</li>
                <li id="Nav2_2">Nav2 Item2</li>
                <li id="Nav2_3">Nav2 Item3</li>
                <li id="Nav2_4">Nav2 Item4</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JavaScript w/ jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var isDebugMode = true;

    //Set common sort settings for all lists
    $(".sortable").sortable({
        opacity: 0.6,
        cursor: 'move'
    });

    //Function used to configure update calls for each sort
    function setSortAction(selector, updatePage, updateAction, itemLabel) {
        $(selector).sortable({
            update: function () {
                var itemList = $(this).sortable(
                    "serialize", {
                    attribute: "id",
                    key: itemLabel
                });

                //Create POST request to persist the update
                var bodyContent = "action=" + updateAction + "&" + itemList;
                if (isDebugMode) { alert("DEBUG: bodyContent = \n" + bodyContent); }
                //$.post(updatePage, bodyContent, function (postResult) { alert(postResult); });
            }
        });
    }

    //Set sort update action for top level and second level
    setSortAction(".navLevel1", "updateDB.php", "updateMenuListings", "record");
    setSortAction(".navLevel2", "updateDB.php", "updateMenuItemListings", "record");

});
```